# Dynamically Adding (Selecting/unselecting) a column in datagrid Kendo UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am just started with kendo UI grids, And I could able to make out how to integrate the kendo with angularJS

Ex: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/teisaacs21w/6k5km7nb/)

But I was trying to implement some thing like dynamically adding/selecting or unselecting the column names, then the data grid should display the columns accordingly in the data table.

Ex: [image: BY Default consider few columns are selecet]

Now when I selecting a new column in the right side of the grid, The datatable is updated with that selected column

Hope this image gives a clear idea on what I am pointing

[image: New Column Selected]

So, I want to achieve this kind of dynamic data grid,

Even Though I make

```
columns: [
            { field: "lastName", title: "Last Name" },
            { field: "firstName", title: "First Name" },
            { field: "company", title: "Company"},
            { field: "title", title: "Title" },
            { field: "email", title: "Email" },
            { field: "phone", title: "Phone" }
        ],
```

and dataSource Dynamic it is not working.

NOTE: Please Consider the columns names are fetched from API, so I need to implement dynamically based on API

Answer (score 0):

for showing/hiding columns we have methods exposed on Grid itself. Here is the API ref of those:

showColumn - http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-showColumn

hideColumn - http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-hideColumn

Also, we have a feature called ColumnMenu. It automatically provides a column menu where you can check/ uncheck the columns to show or hide. Here is a demo of that: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/column-menu

hope this helps

Comment: I am looking into angularjs integration with kendo UI, and here I have some thing, hope you can help me in this : http://plnkr.co/edit/RFMTQcpzWEzN6uUs1mIU?p=preview, In this I could not able to see the datagrid displaying

Comment: can you please help me in this, I have a seperate issue in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33778706/not-able-to-refresh-the-data-grid-after-selecting-the-column-dynamically