# Not able to refresh the data grid after selecting the column dynamically

Tags: jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am just started with kendo UI grids, And I could able to make out how to integrate the kendo with angularJS.

But I was trying to implement some thing like dynamically adding/selecting or unselecting the column names, then the data grid should display the columns accordingly in the data table.

Ex: [image: BY Default consider few columns are selecet]

Now when I selecting a new column in the right side of the grid, The datatable is updated with that selected column

Hope this image gives a clear idea on what I am pointing

[image: New Column Selected]

So, I want to achieve this kind of dynamic data grid,

I tried the to implement a sample, in [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/btjgzkup/33/) . In this jsfiddle you can find the datagrid with one column but, when you select a column by selecting a checkbox, above the datagrid, then could not able to reload/refresh  the datagrid.

```
//vm.gridOptions.refresh(); THIS SAYS ERROR
```

ERROR:

```
TypeError: vm.gridOptions.refresh is not a function
    at vm.addColumsn (
```

NOTE: Please Consider the columns names are fetched from API, so I need to implement dynamically based on API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed the options doesn't have a refresh method. This is a [method](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-refresh) of the Kendo UI widget which won't help you achieve your goal.

You need to use the k-rebind directive in order to set options at runtime:

`<kendo-grid k-options="vm.gridOptions" k-rebind="vm.gridOptions"></kendo-grid>`

Here is a live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/btjgzkup/34/

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay, Sorry to tell you, but I think the jsfiddle is not updated,

Comment: Seems updated to me. Try this one http://jsfiddle.net/88e5xwkb/. Click the labels (ContactTitle).

Comment: Thanks for helping, k-rebind is the trick, I think my logic of adding/removing the column is incorrect, will work on it, Thanks very much buddy, will ask you if I get in some more issues :)